# Redirecting to Dashboard while clicking on Print button in Magento 2 backend

Tags: magento2, custom, plugin

I have created a custom button, I am trying to print order details. 
I am using plugin for this

**di.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View">
    <plugin name="addMyButton" type="Pulsestorm\MenuTutorial\Plugin\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View"/>
   </type>
</config>
```

**View.php**

```
 <?php
namespace Pulsestorm\MenuTutorial\Plugin\Block\Adminhtml\Order;

class View{
   protected $urlBuider;
   public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlBuilder
   ) {
       $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
     }
    public function beforeSetLayout(\Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View $view)
  {
    $url = $this->urlBuilder->getUrl('pulsestorm_menututorial/print/order_id'.$view->getOrderId() );
    $newString = implode('/',str_split($url,73));
    //$url = '/mymodule/controller/action/id/' . $view->getOrderId();


    $view->addButton(
        'order_myaction',
        [
            'label' => __('CustomPrint'),
            'class' => 'print',
            'onclick' => "setLocation('{$newString}')"
        ]
    );
  }         
}
```

**Controller path is Pulsestorm\MenuTutorial\Controller and Controller name is PrintAction**

[image]
When i clicking CustomPrint button it is redirecting me on dashnoard. please help.

Comment: $newString is your final url, is this correct display, have you debug?

Comment: One min i show you exact url

Comment: http://127.0.0.1/magento/2.1/admin/pulsestorm_menututorial/print/order_id/270/key/ed33c1838f0879ef62e6f9298c9fe8d0992c7b99452b8005e03fcf881bd4b14a/

Comment: I am not sure that this url will go to execute function of controller. You can tell me better way if this is wrong.

Comment: you have to debug if function is execute or not?

Comment: which function ?

Comment: above beforesetlayout function

Comment: Yes it is working fine button is displaying but when i click on this button it redirect me to dashboard

Comment: As you can see CustomButton on order view page

Comment: you can try with 'onclick' => 'setLocation(\'' . $newString . '\')' in above onclick value remove var and check

Comment: Same result @Rakesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it from myself I created a routes.xml undet etc/admin.html and give admin as route id and defined frontname as pulsestorm_menututorial. And finally I put my controller file PrintAction.php under Controller/Adminhtml/Order folder. Now url will be http://127.0.0.1/magento/2.1/admin/pulsestorm_menututorial/order/printaction/id/270/key/48628201112efdcfd8196ca49db1f746ada8711cf24bfe87870e9e2f03f9a647

Where order is folder name inside Adminhtml folder and printaction is controller name.
If still it is issue then remove var/ folder and try again

Answer (score 0):

I think  You form must have form key to allow submit data.

Reference:

http://ka.lpe.sh/2012/09/13/magento-submitting-form-in-admin-redirects-to-dashboard/

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/6ea7d2d85cded3fa0fbcf4e7aa0dcd4edbf568a6/app/code/Magento/Backend/view/adminhtml/templates/admin/formkey.phtml

Comment: I already have key you can see url  " http://127.0.0.1/magento/2.1/admin/pulsestorm_menututorial/print/order_id/270/key/ed33c1838f0879ef62e6f9298c9fe8d0992c7b99452b8005e03fcf881bd4b14a/  "

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check database, *core_config_data* table.
Run below query in DB

```
UPDATE `core_config_data` SET `value` = '0' WHERE `core_config_data`.`path` like 'advanced/modules_disable_output/Magento_AdminNotification';
```

This query enables the Admin Notification module and issue get resolved.